# IBM Mobile first 7.0 build all environment Failed Running Android Studio:

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

My IBM MobileFirst v 7.0 project is not able to build an Android application. I'm getting the message below.

```
[2015-04-22 17:32:15] FWLST1125W: Android build will fail because an Android SDK was not installed. Use the Android SDK Manager to install API level 21, configure 
your project to build with API level 21 by updating the Project Build Target in Project / Properties / Android dialog. 
[2015-04-22 17:32:22]             Failed Running Android Studio: Specify location of Android Studio in Window->Preferences->MobileFirst
```

And I have given the right path of Android Studio.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is too broad. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: **Android SDK was not installed. Use the Android SDK Manager to install API level 21, configure your project to build with API level 21 by updating the Project Build Target in Project / Properties / Android dialog.** it is telling you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 2):

In MobileFirst Platform you have two development paths for Android applications:

1. Use Google's ADT tools; this will enable MobileFirst Studio to generate an Android project for the Hybrid application

   If you do not have the ADT Eclipse plug-in installed you will receive this warning:

   > FWLST1125W: Android build will fail because an Android SDK was not
   >   installed. Use the Android SDK Manager to install API level 21,
   >   configure  your project to build with API level 21 by updating the
   >   Project Build Target in Project / Properties / Android dialog.
2. Use Android Studio; even if you have Android Studio set-up, you will still get the above warning in MobileFirst Studio - we're aware of this and have a ticket open about it. In this case, you can disregard the warning.

   To use Android Studio from MobileFirst Studio, go to Eclipse > Preferences... > MobileFirst and set the path to the *folder that contains Android Studio*. For example, in Mac that would be `/Applications`.